# extract all parents from a doc with Nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a document like that:

```
<DL><a lot of tags>...<H3>Entry 1</H3><a lot of tags>...</DL>
<DL><a lot of tags>...<H3>Entry 2</H3><a lot of tags>...
    <DL><a lot of tags>...<H3>Entry 21</H3><a lot of tags>...
        <DL><a lot of tags>...<H3>Entry 211</H3><a lot of tags>...</DL>
    </DL>
</DL>
<DL><a lot of tags>...><H3>Entry 3</H3><a lot of tags>...</DL>
```

I want to find all ''entry and it's easy with the follow code:

```
@doc=Nokogiri::HTML(@file)
@doc.css('DL>h3').each do |node| puts node.text end
```

how can I extract a list of H3 parents for any entries ? 
I'd like to have a method as 'parent' that returns the relationship, i.e.:
entry211.parent ==> /Entry 2/Entry 21/

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want the parent element of each `h3` element

```
@doc.css('DL>h3').collect(&:parent)
```

should do the trick.

However, it looks like you might want all `h3` elements that are children of a `dl` element that is an ancestor of a `h3` element. If I've understood that and your structure correctly you should be able to do

```
@doc.css('dl>h3').collect { |h3| h3.ancestors('dl').css('h3') }
```

This gives you an `Array` containing an `Array` with the `h3` elements that are descendants of the `dl` elements in each `h3` elements ancestry. Confused? I sure am :)

For example, using your sample HTML the result for the Entry 211 `h3` is

```
@doc.css('dl>h3').collect { |h3| h3.ancestors('dl').css('h3') }[3].collect(&:text)
#=> ["Entry 211", "Entry 21", "Entry 2"]
```

Is this close enough to what you want?